# make a record read-only in vTiger once it is saved

Tags: vtiger

I have a question please..

how can I make a record become read-only once a particular field has a particular value. for eg. status field has the value "validate"

Think you :)

Answer (score 0):

Vtiger does not offer that functionality through configuration means. However you can create a "before save" event handler. That is code that gets executed every time a record gets saved (but just before the saving is final).

In a nutshell, you have to first create the handler (a php class that extends the `VTEventHandler` class), then inside that class create the function `handleEvent($eventName, $entityData)`. Inside the function you would write your logic. Finally, you have to register your handler by calling vtlib's `Vtiger_Event::register`.

In your event handler you can check what the value of the field was before being edited and after it was edited (but before being saved). So, if the field value prior to editing was "validate", in your code you just have to make sure that value stays that way.

You can find more on event handlers here: https://wiki.vtiger.com/index.php/Eventing

Comment: Thank you for your reply Ruben, In fact I had already proceed like that, but my issue with the code to do to change the isEditable() and isDeletable() to be 0. that can make the record read-only i think..! i did this code but it didn't work for me if ($valid == "Validate"){ $viewer = new Vtiger_Viewer(); $viewer->assign('IS_MODULE_EDITABLE', 0); $viewer->assign('IS_MODULE_DELETABLE',0); }

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Could you post the whole code on your question? Please also indicate where you are putting that code.

Comment: function handleEvent($eventName, $data) {
  global $adb;
  $module           = $data->getModuleName();
  
  if ($eventName === 'vtiger.entity.beforesave' AND $module === "CallsEvaluationGrid") {
    require_once 'modules/CallsEvaluationGrid/CallsEvaluationGrid.php';    
    $valid = $data->get('valid');
    if ($valid == "Valide") {
     $viewer = new Vtiger_Viewer();
     $viewer->assign('IS_MODULE_EDITABLE', 0);
     $viewer->assign('IS_MODULE_DELETABLE', 0);}}

Comment: i put this code in my class handler: modules/CallsEvaluationGrid/handlers/RecordUpdater.php